# Return 0 if the condition doesn't match

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, sum, where-clause

I have a soccer game where people can predict matches. They can give a match a 1 if they think the home team wins, a 2 if the away club wins and a 3 for a draw. If they predict a match correctly, they get a point. The tables in my database look like this:

Table matches

```
| id  | home     | away      | result | round_id
| --- | ---------| -------- -| -------|----------|
| 1   | id club 1| id club 2 | 1      | id round 1 
| 2   | id club 5| id club 4 | 3      | id round 1
| 3   | id club 8| id club 5 | 1      | id round 2

Table predictions

| prediction | user_id      | match_id |
| -------- | -------------- | -------- |
| 1        | id user 1      | id match 1 
| 3        | id user 1      | id match 2
| 2        | id user 1      | id match 3
```

Initially I wanted to do the calculation of the score in PHP, but I think this should also be possible via MySQL only. So I tried something and came up with the following query:

```
SELECT Count(*) AS points,
       username,
       round_id
FROM   predictions
       LEFT JOIN matches
              ON predictions.match_id = matches.id
       INNER JOIN users
               ON predictions.user_id = users.id
WHERE  predictions.prediction = matches.result
GROUP  BY username,
          round_id
ORDER  BY points DESC,
          username ASC
```

The query calculates the score per round per user correctly, the only problem is that if a participant has nothing right in a game round, it will not appear in the list at all. Does anyone have any idea what to do to also get a participant in the list if they have 0 points? Translated to the tables mentioned above, round 2 will not return the query because the only match in it was mispredicted. I do want this, however, and so that round 2 is returned with a score of 0.

Result I want:

```
| points   | username       | round_id|
| -------- | -------------- | --------|
| 2        | John           | 1 
| 0        | John           | 2
```

Result I have now:

```
| points   | username       | round_id|
| -------- | -------------- | --------|
| 2        | John           | 1
```

Comment: Your question is a little bit confusing. Try to edit and clarify what do you mean? Did you mean if the first round prediction is wrong then the second round prediction is worthless even if its the right prediction??? And about the showing the score of ```0``` if you just remove the ```WHERE``` statement and condition it will show all users and prediction. (Actually that ```WHERE``` statement is the reason of filtering which you do not desire)

Comment: I want the 'total' points of every round per user. Also when a user gets no point in a round, than it's 0 points.
When I remove the WHERE a user gets points for every match, regardless of whether the prediction is right.

Comment: Just remove ```WHERE``` statement and condition so that you probably get your desired result.

Comment: Shouldn't `LEFT JOIN matches` be `OUTER JOIN matches` if you want all results?

Comment: @kmoser With OUTER JOIN matches I unfortunately get the same result. Fortunately, forpas's solution works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE  predictions.prediction = matches.result
```

filters out any wrong predictions, but even if you remove it, the aggregate function `COUNT(*)` would count the wrong predictions also.

Join and group like this:

```
SELECT SUM(p.prediction = m.result) AS points,
       u.username,
       m.round_id
FROM users u 
INNER JOIN predictions p ON p.user_id = u.id
INNER JOIN matches m ON m.id = p.match_id
GROUP BY u.id, u.username, m.round_id
ORDER  BY points DESC, u.username ASC;
```

The aggregate function `SUM()` will sum the boolean expressions `prediction = result` which are evaluated as `1` for `true` and `0` for `false`.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b0e656c63b6a0ae2d3b4804448b29508).

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thanks!
By the way, I added WHERE m.result IS NOT NULL to only get rows from rounds where there's a result.